# Assistance checking values in a database vs values entered in a log in form in Visual Studio 2010 and using MS Access 2010

Tags: c#, database

Below is the code that is executed when the user clicks the submit button. However, everytime I try it I get an error which reads "Syntax error in FROM clause"

What I'm trying to do is check the values entered in te login screen against the values stored in the database, but there seems to be an issue with my FROM clause that I am not picking up on. Any pointers are appreciated.

string userName = "";
            string passWord = "";

```
        userName = txtUserName.Text;
        passWord = txtPassword.Text;




        string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\kazan_000\Desktop\Risk Manager\Risk Manager\Risk Manager Database 2.0.accdb";

        string cmdText = "SELECT * from User where userName=? and passWord=?";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", passWord);
            int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");

            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Credentials, Please Re-Enter");
        }
```

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: @user3290378: it seems you are using reserved words in your query , so enclose your parameters in square brackets, for mre info see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** `user` and `password`  are reserved words in MS-Access .

**Solution :** you need to enclose the reserved words in square brackets `[]`

Try This:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * from [User] where userName=? and [passWord]=?";
```

Comment: I tried this. Now it's giving me a new error that states "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: @user3290378: what is the input `username` and `password` values? does it contain single quotes?

Comment: userName and passWord's values are the values the user enters into the log in form txtUserName and txtPassWord text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Strange mixture you have there.

`"Select * From [User] Where userName = @p1 and [password] = @p2"` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried your answer and I'm still getting a syntax error in the From clause. Is there something about the syntax when communicating with an MS Access 2010 database that I'm missing?

Comment: Reserved words apparently, Square brackets would sort that e.g. [User], should also be able ti use the more generic double quotes.